# How can I append the content of one map to another map?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, append, stdmap

I have the following two maps:

```
map< string, list < string > > map1;
map< string, list < string > > map2;
```

I populated `map1` with the following content:

```
1. kiran; c:\pf\kiran.mdf, c:\pf\kiran.ldf
2. test;  c:\pf\test.mdf, c:\pf\test.mdf
```

Then I copied the content of `map1` into `map2` as follows:

```
map2 = map1;
```

Then I filled `map1` again with the following new content:

```
1. temp; c:\pf\test.mdf, c:\pf\test.ldf
2. model; c:\model\model.mdf, c:\pf\model.ldf
```

Now I have to append this content to `map2`. I cannot use `map2 = map1;`, because this will overwrite the existing content in `map2`. So, how can I do this?

Comment: It looks like that's the right way to do it according to the documentation: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator=/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator=/)

Comment: How does it happen that you and user Cute ask very similar questions at almost the same moments???

Comment: Okay, but what's the point in asking the question twice? One of you could ask the question and then both of you could see the answers. Question duplication just dilutes the community effort and you get less good answers.

Comment: (I have merged these two identical questions)

Answer (score 66):

```
map<int,int> map1;
map<int,int> map2;
map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end());
```

This will insert into `map1` the elements from the beginning to the end of `map2`. This method is standard to all STL data structure, so you could even do something like

```
map<int,int> map1;
vector<pair<int,int>> vector1;
vector1.insert(map1.begin(), map1.end());
```

Furthermore, pointers can also function as iterators!

```
char str1[] = "Hello world";
string str2;
str2.insert(str1, str1+strlen(str1));
```

Highly recommend studying the magic of the STL and iterators!

Comment: Remember the space between the two `> >` :)

Comment: Oh yes, certain compilers will complain about nested template parameters (*cough* GCC), as the >> looks like a stream extraction operator. So you may need a space in the middle. I come from a Windows world, though, and the compiler in Visual Studio does the right thing. :)

Comment: In C++1x space between >> is not necessary.

Comment: use `std::make_move_iterator` if map2 is not needed.

Answer (score 8):

You can use use insert method of the map. For example:

```
   std::map<int, int> map1;
    std::map<int, int> map2;

    map1[1] = 1;

    map2.insert(map1.begin(), map1.end());
    map1.clear();

    map1[2] =2;
    map2.insert(map1.begin(), map1.end());
```

Comment: Its just an example..it means the key val : 1 maps to value 1 :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this several ways depending on what you want to do:

1. Use the copy constructor:

   ```
   map< string, list < string > > map1;
   // fill in map1

   map< string, list < string > > map2(map1);
   ```
2. Use the assignment operator as you indicate in the question:

   ```
   map< string, list < string > > map1;
   map< string, list < string > > map2;

   // fill in map1

   map2 = map1;
   ```
3. Do it all yourself manually:

   ```
   map< string, list < string > > map1;
   map< string, list < string > > map2;

   // fill in map1

   for (map< string, list < string > >::iterator i = map1.begin();
        i <= map1.end(); ++i) {
     map2[i.first()] = i.second();
   }
   ```

It sounds like (1) is what you want.

Comment: I'd like to add:
std::copy(map1.begin(), map1.end(), insert_iterator(map2, map2.begin()) is another way

Answer (score 1):

Since [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) provides a [`merge()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge) member function. It allows you to extract content from one map and insert it into another map. Example code based on your data could be written as follows:

```
using myMap = std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>>;

myMap  map2 = { {"kiran", {"c:\\pf\\kiran.mdf", "c:\\pf\\kiran.ldf"}},
                {"test",  {"c:\\pf\\test.mdf",  "c:\\pf\\test.mdf"}} };

myMap  map1 = { {"temp",  {"c:\\pf\\test.mdff",    "c:\\pf\\test.ldf"}},
                {"model", {"c:\\model\\model.mdf", "c:\\pf\\model.ldf"}} };

map2.merge(map1);

for (auto const &kv : map2) {
    std::cout << kv.first << " ->";
    for (auto const &str : kv.second)
        std::cout << " " << str;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> kiran -> c:\pf\kiran.mdf c:\pf\kiran.ldf
>   model -> c:\model\model.mdf c:\pf\model.ldf
>   temp -> c:\pf\test.mdff c:\pf\test.ldf
>   test -> c:\pf\test.mdf c:\pf\test.mdf

Notes:

- A key can only exist once in a map (i.e. `kiran`, `test`, `temp`, `model` in your example). If both maps contain the same key, then the corresponding element will not be merged into `map2` and remain in `map1`.
- If all elements can be merged into `map2`, then `map1` will become empty.
- The `merge()` function is quite efficient, because element are neither copied nor moved. Instead, only the internal pointers of the map nodes are redirected.

[Code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c51b39cc54945ed)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert your map as you define it, this is nice:

```
payload.insert({
            { "key1", "one" },
            { "key2", 2 },
        });
```